# Как получить кастомную дату-время на питоне в стандарте RFC 3339?

Tags: python, дата, datetime, timestamp

Нужно получить из БД дату и время и сделать из низ timestamp в формате RFC 3339, потому что апи гугл календаря принимает только такой формат.

Т.к. из БД дата (`item[14]`) возвращается в виде `datetime.date(2023, 6, 8)`, а время (`item[15]`) в виде `datetime.timedelta(seconds=44725)`, преобразую их так:

```
for_time=str(item[15]).split(":")
datetime(item[14].year,item[14].month,item[14].day,int(for_time[0]),int(for_time[1]),int(for_time[2]))
    print(utc_dt.isoformat())
```

Получаю на выходе `2023-06-08T12:25:25`
А нужно получать в формате RFC 3339 с UTM смещением (в моем случае нужно задать +7) примерно так `2023-06-08T12:25:25.544600+07:00`

Не могу найти как мне это сделать, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Смещение автоматически появится, если в объекте datetime будет прописано это самое смещение. Откуда его брать? Откуда вы знаете, что в вашем случае нужно задать именно +7? А вы не забываете учесть переход на летнее/зимнее время и прочую подобную дребедень?

Answer (score 0):

Сложить дату и дельту - получится датавремя. Там есть метод для перевода в исо готовый. Чтоб не мучать себя с часовым поясом храните и передавайте в utc. Но и стандартном типе есть метод который устанавливает часовой пояс как явный.

> ...примерно так `2023-06-08T12:25:25.544600+07:00`

```
>>> now=datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.astimezone().isoformat()
'2023-06-30T11:04:59.558080+03:00'
>>> now.astimezone(datetime.UTC).isoformat()
'2023-06-30T08:04:59.558080+00:00'
```

Comment: Я использовал готовый метод (utc_dt.isoformat()) он переводит в формат ISO 8601, а мне надо в RFC 3339 . 
Как синтаксически мне изменить код чтобы передать в кастомные дату-время UTC?